# CVS-styled tags implementation in git

Tags: git, tags

I faced with the strange question, that I cannot answer by myself, despite I've been working with git for long time.

Process requires to tag single file in `git` when it'll be considered production ready. When other files become 'ready' too they need to be 'tagged' as well. File was tagged first might change till that moment, but we still need to be able to retrieve all 'ready' files at once.

It would work, if it is possible to tag single file in commit, but it is not true.

Could you give me any clue, workaround, how I could achieve this: retrieving several files in several commits linked together by single criterion?

Comment: This sounds like someone with a CVS background designed the workflow (where you apply tags individually to each file at specific revisions). `git` doesn't work that way, but rather a tag applies to a specific commit, which implies a specific state for every file in the project. You can apply a tag to an individual file, but only that one file - you would need other tags for every individual file, which would quickly get unmanageable, I think...

Comment: You're right, workflow was designed by one of old-school guys, and despite I need at least to try to implement it...

Comment: I am forced to do that non-sense at work as well tho for other reasons. The workplace's 'official' tool is an antiquated software suite that is very similar to CVS. I unofficially use `git` for all of my dev and it keeps everything nice and tidy. The issue is that to keep the upper's happy, I need to still commit changes to the older system. After I check-in a changeset, I will label (tag) all of those specific files (and those specific versions) with the SHA id of the git commit. This allows me to treat the older system just as if it were git. Doing a `Get` by label is ~= to a commit.

Comment: @g19fanatic could you describe what you're doing in more details (i.e. git commands?) as a separate answer? It looks like it might be an solution for me as well. I'm asking since if it'll help me I would like to accept your approach as the answer. I cannot treat comments like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for git's flexibility we have found the answer! The solution has its own drawbacks, but it works.

The idea is simple. All `production-ready` changes will be tracked in separate branch and files will appear there not via merge with development branch, but via checking out only required files from it.

Despite we're loosing all pre-`production-ready` history we'll receive clean and simple way how to retrieve all `production-ready` files in one go.

In our defense I might add, that this history issue could be leveled by adding to the commit message in `pre-production` branch id of the commit from which file was checked out. And it is also possible to simplify the process by writhing simple git command that will perform series of needed commands.

These commands are:

```
git checkout pre-production
```

to switch to the `pre-production` branch.

```
git checkout development file/name
```

to checkout needed file from `development` branch.

```
git commit -m "Moving file/name to pre-production from commit id 5364afb23"
```

to commit and label the movement.

Comment: How do you know that you're not missing some files?

Comment: This is similar to question, how I will know do I missed to 'tag' some files or not? When I'm 'tagging' file to be `pre-production`-ready, I'm moving it into another branch. If I missed this operation, I broke the workflow. The issue here is that workflow is already broken — I'm required to decompose repository by such tagging, instead of using standard, secure `git` tags.

Comment: This workflow is just FUBAR... What you should do is creating a `release` branch from the `development` branch, use a simple text file to keep track of which files are ready and merge all changes in the `release` branch back into `development`. Once the `release` branch is finished, tag it and create a `maintenance` branch from it.

Comment: I know, I know how to to things in the right way. I was forced to come up with `git` based solution for old `CVS` workflow. Because white collars are ready to switch from `CVS` to `git`, but don't want to change their comfortable workflow. That's it. You will ask, what's the reason to use `git` than? The answer is: I'm confused too.

Comment: Perhaps a more robust solution than the one you proposed would then be a *manifest* file where each line contains the hash and the path of the *pre-production* files. A release-script then reads that file and exports the tree to another directory.

Comment: Frankly speaking, I don't see why this manifest approach is more robust. I can add file more than one there, I'll will stick to the commit ids, what basically means I could not rebase development branch anymore not to lose consistency, this manifest file also need to be maintained in git, so I will have bunch of 'updating manifest file' commits. And in addition checkout procedure will be much more complex.

Answer (score 1):

Tagging files for purposes like that requires that the branch that file is checked into does not change, e.g. if some version on the branch is tagged and then the branch is rebases, then the tag will still point to the "old" version and not follow onto the "new" branch. So for a "files not yet delivered" scenario, tagging will probably not work well.

What I think would work better would be to create a special `production_ready` branch and then cherry-pick the changes you think is production ready onto that branch. That way, when the actual "deliver to production" shall occur, you just merge the `production_ready` branch.

Comment: Does it mean I should have only one file per commit that intended to be cherry-picked?

Answer (score 1):

As per your request,

Do your development of software using git. Do the normal `git add .` and `git commit -m "commit message"` process of adding new changes to the index and commiting them to your repository as needed.

At the end of the day, you will want to make the uppers happy and check-in all of your current work to the other CM system. The issue is that this system requires you to tag/label every file instead of a "set" of files. You can handle this problem by tagging all of the files of the product that is in the older CM system immediately after the check-in with a tag that matches the SHAID hash of the corresponding git commit (reachable by typing `git log`).

This allows you to have a one to one record for a set of files that correspond to a specific git commit.